# Java GUI takes too long to open

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a Java program which currently only interfaces via the console. I am now working on creating a simple graphical user interface in Eclipse to allow the user to interact with the program. The GUI as it currently stands, is only a very basic one- just an 'example' to get something up and running and displaying on screen.

However, for some reason, it takes far too long to open up when I click 'run' on the class in Eclipse... I have to wait for between 30 seconds and 1 minute for it to open after clicking 'run', even though the console would seem to indicate that it is running straight away (the 'stop' button at the top of the console becomes 'clickable' as soon as I click run). When the GUI does eventually open, all it displays is a text area with the word "hello", which is what I expect- so it does run correctly.

With previous Java applications I've written, they GUI would usually open no longer than five seconds after clicking 'run'. Does anyone have any idea why this is taking so long, or what I should do to get it to open quicker? My Gui.java class currently looks like this:

```
package openDIS;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Gui extends JFrame{

public String text = "";
public int rows = 20;
public int columns = 5;

public Gui(){
    setTitle("DIS Filter");
    setSize(1000, 500);
    setLocation (10, 10);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    initGui();
}

/*public quitButton(){
    initGui();
} */

private void initGui(){
    //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("DIS Filter");
    this.setSize(1000, 500);

    panel.setLayout(null);
    /*Add a JTextArea to display the output DIS information */
    JTextArea displayOutput = new JTextArea(text, rows, columns);
    displayOutput.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
    panel.add(displayOutput);
    displayOutput.setEditable(false);
    //displayOutput.setEditable(false);
    add(panel);
    displayOutput.append("hello");


    //String data = EspduReceiver.espdu;
//  EspduReceiver.receivePdu(); /*The code underneath here will never be reached unless I specify how long to perform this method call for- */
                                /*Since the receivePdu() method has no 'end' condition- it keeps looping continually until told to stop */
                                /*Try using a timer to specify how long it should be called for */
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + 60*1000; /* 60 seconds * 1000 ms/sec */
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end){

        int n = EspduReceiver.entitySite.size(); /*This is what to use, but set n to 10 for testing purposes. */
        //int n = 10;
        System.out.print(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
//          EspduReceiver.receivePdu();
            System.out.print("Entered 'for' loop. ");
            System.out.println(EspduReceiver.entitySite.get(i));
            System.out.println(EspduReceiver.entityApplication.get(i));
            System.out.println(EspduReceiver.entity.get(i));
            displayOutput.append(EspduReceiver.entitySite.get(i).toString());
            displayOutput.append(EspduReceiver.entityApplication.get(i).toString());
            displayOutput.append(EspduReceiver.entity.get(i).toString());
        }       
    }




    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
    panel.add(quitButton);
    quitButton.setBounds(875, 400, 80, 30); /*Set the location of the button in the window, and its size */


    quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });


    panel.add(quitButton);
    //setTitle("Quit");
    //setSize(60,30); /*This line was overwriting the previously set values for the size of the window */
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    panel.repaint();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
}

public static void main(String[] args){ /* I probably don't need a main method here- I have one in EspduReceiver.java */
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Gui gui = new Gui();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}




}
```

Comment: The reason is the strange while loop and that you set the visibility to true after that loop.

Comment: I think so too. You should not do business logic stuff in the creation of your gui. Just create a GUI, display it and then launch a separate thread that does whatever your loop does. Let that separate thread update your GUI so that the user sees the progress.

Comment: Brilliant- that's sorted it. Thanks very much!